# gunzip not finding files even though it knows file names

Tags: bash, zip, gzip

I have a simple bash script that unzips a bunch of files in a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound
gunzip -f $dir/*gz*
```

Yet when I run this command I get these errors:

```
gzip: /volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012650001_012675000.sdf.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012675001_012700000.sdf.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012700001_012725000.sdf.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012725001_012750000.sdf.gz: No such file or directory
... [this continues on for every file in the directory]
```

Clearly It's finding every file in the directory because the filenames are listed in the  error, but then it fails to unzip them and says the file is not found. What is going on here?

**edit** some of the files do actually get unzipped, but the error for that file is still shown

Comment: Could `/volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012725001_012750000.sdf.gz` be a link?

Comment: No these are all files I've placed in the directory manually.

Comment: Mind checking if those files really have readable permissions? `[[ -r /volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp/compound/Compound_012700001_012725000.sdf.gz ]] && echo readable`

Comment: here is the output for `ls -al` on that directory 

    `-r--r--r-- 1 kharland jhuangroup   5609 Jul  6 15:30 Compound_009525001_009550000.sdf.gz`

all of the files have these exact permissions.  Interesting suggestion, I didn't think to do that.


I also just realized you gave me a command, the output came out empty

Comment: I can guess that it's a bug somewhere. If not in gunzip, it may be in one of the libraries. Does it make a difference if you use `gzip -d /path/to/file.gz` instead? And I'm curious about your gzip's version: `gzip --version`.

Comment: I'll try that instead, Forgot to mention this script is running as a cron-job if that would have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find the likely reason: When you run `gunzip -f $dir/*gz*`, the files gets expanded and passed as arguments to `gunzip`. Filename expansion only happens once and is not dynamic. Arguments would remain the way they were even if files get deleted or renamed. Somehow if some of your files gets deleted before `gzip` starts processing them (due to the fact that decompressing each file would take time before it gets to the other), then surely those messages would appear.

To prevent those messages you can check each file if they still exist before processing:

```
for file in "$dir"/*gz; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && gunzip -f "$file"
done
```

- Better quote `$dir` to prevent word splitting.
- If the target filenames are those that end in `gz` then don't an extra `*` at the end.

Comment: This seemed to do it! Thank you very much